# Openzeppelin ERC20 make revert

Tags: solidity, revert, erc20, openzeppelin

my intent is making ERC721 token can transfer by my ERC20 token only

the transfer flow is

1. Buyer approve ERC20 to Seller.
2. Seller transfer ERC721 to Buyer.
3. My ERC721 Token's transfer function transfer ERC20 to Seller from Buyer first, and transfer ERC721 to Buyer from Seller.

revert error occur to ERC20 transfer step.

i try to every single line delete to find revert point.
and i found that.

this is my test code

```
const token20 = artifacts.require("MyToken20");
const token721 = artifacts.require("MyToken721");

contract("Test", async()=>{

//...

  // Buyer token20 approve to Seller
  it("Token20 approve", async()=>{
    var value = web3.toWei(token721Price, "ether");
    await contract20.approve(seller, value, {from:buyer});

    var allowed = await contract20.allowance(buyer, seller);
    allowed = web3.fromWei(allowed, "ether");
    assert.equal(allowed, token721Price);
  });

  // Seller transfer token721 to Buyer
  // token20 transfer to Seller inside of function transferMy721
  it("Token721 transfer", async()=>{
    var allowed = await contract20.allowance(buyer, seller);
    allowed = web3.fromWei(allowed, "ether");
    assert.equal(allowed, token721Price);

    await contract721.transferMy721(buyer, token721Id, {from:seller});  // <--- revert here

    var newOwner = await contract721.ownerOf(token721Id);
    assert.equal(newOwner, buyer);
  });

});
```

and revert point in my contract is here

```
contract MyToken721 is ERC721Token{                                                       
  string public name = "My ERC721 Token Product";                                         
  string public symbol = "MTP";                                                           

  mapping(uint256 => uint256) my721TokenPrice;                                            

  MyToken20 token;                                                                        

  constructor(MyToken20 _token) public ERC721Token(name, symbol){                         
    require(_token != address(0));                                                        
    token = _token;                                                                       
  }                                                                                       

  function mint(address _to, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) public {                   
    _mint(_to, _tokenId);                                                                 
    my721TokenPrice[_tokenId] = _price;                                                   
  }                                                                                       

  function transferMy721(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public returns(bool){             
    require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenId));                                             

    uint256 tokenPrice = my721TokenPrice[_tokenId];                                       

    if( token.transferFrom(_to, msg.sender, tokenPrice) == false )  // <--- revert here   
      return false;                                                                       

    super.approve(_to, _tokenId);                                                         
    super.transferFrom(msg.sender, _to, _tokenId);                                        

    return true;                                                                          
  }                                                                                       
//...                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

and revert point in ERC20 StandardToken contract is here

```
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {                                 

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;         

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)                                                                           
    public returns (bool)
  {                                                                           
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);                                       
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);  // <--- revert here       
    require(_to != address(0));                                               

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);                            
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);                                
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);      
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);                                        
    return true;                                                              
  }  
//...
}
```

as you can see, in my test code, i double check

```
allowed[_from][msg.sender]
```

please check my full code [here](https://gist.github.com/Twibap/b7d7501b9e24f592ffaca3de18bc947c)

Answer (score 0):

the one calling transferFrom is my erc721 contract.
so, i change test code

`await contract20.approve(seller, value, {from:buyer});`

change to

`await contract20.approve(contract721.address, value, {from:buyer});`

thank you for SylTi